# Syntax error while passing values in alloy script function

Tags: liferay, portlet, alloy-ui

I am dispaying the book details from database. I want to get details of a user who has checked out the book on `onclick` of the button.

My AUI script:

```
<aui:script>
        function displayUserDetails(userId,userName)
        {
            var details="<table><tr><td>"+userId+"</td><td>"+userName+"</td></tr></table>";
            AUI().use('liferay-util-window','aui-io-deprecated',function(A)
            {
                var dialog=Liferay.Util.Window.getWindow(
                {
                    dialog: {
                            title:'userdetails',
                            bodyContent:details,
                            centered:true, 
                            modal: true,
                            width: 500,
                            height: 400
                    }
                 }).render();
            });

        }

        </aui:script>
```

I am calling the function here

```
<aui:button name="button9" value="details" id='getMoreInfo_<%=bookId %>' onclick="displayUserDetails(<%=userId %>,<%=un %>);" />
```

I am getting syntax error that while calling the function on button click (above line)

If i call the function like this...

```
onclick="displayUserDetails('<%=userId %>','<%=un %>');"
```

output will be like `<%=userId%><%=un%>` (in table)

```
onclick="displayUserDetails(<%=userId %>,<%=un %>);"
```

Comment: Can you try `onclick='displayUserDetails(<%=userId %>,"<%=un %>");'`

Comment: Hi Pankaj...tried it...Syntax error again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working.....:-)

onClick='<%="displayUserDetails(\'"+userId+"\',\'"+un+"\');"%>'

credits to

Nishikant sapkal   @ http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/27640265